# WPF: How can I bind my deserialized stream directly onto my datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am able to get existing data from the database to load onto my datagrid and it works just fine. All the lists are binded onto the datagrid alright. However, in one scenario, I just need my deserialized stream to bind directly onto my datagrids. I tried a similar approach to the db one and it doesn't work for some reason. I ran the debugger and both lists that I am binding to separate datagrids do contain the deserialized stream, so they're not null. I think I'm missing something.

Here's what I have done:

```
public static LotInformation DeserializedStream(string filePath) {

        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "lot_information";
        xRoot.IsNullable = false;

        // Create an instance of lotinformation class.
        var lot = new LotInformation();

        // Create an instance of stream writer.
        TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(filePath);

        // Create and instance of XmlSerializer class.
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LotInformation), xRoot);

        // DeSerialize from the StreamReader
        lot = (LotInformation)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(txtReader);

        LotInformation newList = new LotInformation();

        List<Components> DeserialComponentsList = new List<Components>();
        List<Families> DeserialFamiliesList = new List<Families>(); 

        foreach (Components comp in lot.Components)
        {
            newList.Components.Add(comp);
            Console.WriteLine(comp); 
        }


        DeserialComponentsList = newList.Components.ToList(); 

        foreach (Families fam in lot.Families)
        {

            newList.Families.Add(fam);
            Console.WriteLine(fam); 
        }
        DeserialFamiliesList = newList.Families.ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(DeserialComponentsList.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(" "); 
        Console.WriteLine(DeserialFamiliesList.Count);
        // Close the stream reader
        txtReader.Close();

        return lot;
    }
```

Properties:

```
public List<Components> DeserialComponentsList
    {
        get {

            return deserialComponentsList;
        }
        set {
            deserialComponentsList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DeserialComponentsList"); 
        }
    }

    public List<Families> DeserialFamiliesList
    {
        get
        {
            return deserialFamiliesList;
        }
        set
        {
            deserialFamiliesList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DeserialFamiliesList");
        }
```

EDIT: Seems like the properties don't get the list of data passed to them for some reason. The program never runs or reaches the properties after adding the deserialized string to a list. The program only detects the properties when the view first opens (properties are null) but after selecting a file and taking that deserialized xml and putting it into a list and having that list being passed down to the property doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the method was a static method. It be a non-static method and I removed the declared new lists because the properties were already declared previously.

So I changed this `public static LotInformation DeserializedStream(string filePath)` to this:  `public void DeserializedStream(string filePath)`.